# installing new php version 5.6 in ssh server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ssh

So I'm using puTTy with ssh connection to access the server.

I followed the instructions [here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/your-first-lamp-server-on-centosredhat-7).

I have properly installed apache/httpd and mysql/mariadb.

But is stuck when installing php.

right after I enter the command

```
sudo yum install php56w php56w-mysql php56w-mcrypt php56w-gd php56w-curl
```

It would give me this installation result:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                         | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                         | 6.3 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                         | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                       | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
remi-safe                                                                                    | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                      | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
vz-base                                                                                      |  951 B  00:00:00
vz-updates                                                                                   |  951 B  00:00:00
webtatic                                                                                     | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
(1/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                | 846 kB  00:00:00
(2/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                | 6.1 MB  00:00:01
(3/3): remi-safe/primary_db                                                                  | 1.1 MB  00:00:01
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.w7 for package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli = 5.6.31-2.w7 for package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-mysql.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-pdo(x86-64) for package: php56w-mysql-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
Removing php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-cli-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Removing php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-common-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Removing php56w-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-gd-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Removing php56w-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-mcrypt-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Removing php56w-mysql.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-mysqlnd-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Removing php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-pdo-5.6.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.w7 for package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli = 5.6.31-2.w7 for package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.w7 for package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64
---> Package php56w-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-mysql.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.w7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-cli = 5.6.31-2.w7
           Available: php56w-cli-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-cli = 5.6.31-1.w7
Error: Package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.w7
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.w7
Error: Package: php56w-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.w7
           Available: php56w-cli-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.31-1.w7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
openssh-clients-6.6.1p1-25.el7_2.x86_64 has missing requires of openssh = ('0', '6.6.1p1', '25.el7_2')
```

What could suppose be the problem?

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about). - Voted to migrate this question.

Comment: Don't try to use both "remi" and "webtatic". As 5.6.26 already installed from "remi-php56", simply enable it, see https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears because php56w and php packages conflict with each other as they are supplied in different repositories.

php from remi repository is already installed, while php56w from webtatic is going to be installed. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914968/failed-to-install-php-5-6-mssql-centos-7) should help here.

Answer (score 0):

Install Yum-Utils to Manage Repository

```
yum install yum-utils
```

Once EPEL, Remi and yum-utils has been installed, you can now move ahead to install PHP 5.4, PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6 with all required modules on CentOS 6 distribution by enabling remi repository using yum-config-manager

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
```

I tried and it worked. thanks